# Why doesn't Weak::new() work when Rc::downgrade() does?

Tags: rust

I'm creating a function which returns a `Weak` reference to a trait object. In situations where the object cannot be found (it's a lookup function), I want to return an empty `Weak` reference using `Weak::new()`:

```
use std::rc::{self, Rc, Weak};
use std::cell::RefCell;

pub trait Part {}

pub struct Blah {}

impl Part for Blah {}

fn main() {
    let blah = Blah {};
    lookup(Rc::new(RefCell::new(blah)));
}

fn lookup(part: Rc<RefCell<Part>>) -> Weak<RefCell<Part>> {
    if true {
        Rc::downgrade(&part)
    } else {
        Weak::new()
    }
}
```

This has the following error during compilation:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Part + 'static: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied in `std::cell::RefCell<Part + 'static>`
  --> <anon>:19:9
   |
19 |         Weak::new()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^ within `std::cell::RefCell<Part + 'static>`, the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `Part + 'static`
   |
   = note: `Part + 'static` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::cell::RefCell<Part + 'static>`
   = note: required by `<std::rc::Weak<T>>::new`
```

Why is it that I can successfully create a `Weak<RefCell<Part>>` from `Rc::downgrade()` but cannot use the same type to create a new Weak reference with `Weak::new()`?

Is there a way for me to annotate `Weak::new()` to help the compiler or will I have to wrap this in an `Option` to let the user know the part wasn't found?

[Working minimal example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8392420d0ab4af8a29ce4a3ee368a8c7&version=stable&backtrace=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type inferred for `Weak::new()` is `Weak<RefCell<Part>>`, and the `Part` part can not be created because it's a trait!

That's what the `Sized` error is all about. The trait is not a concrete structure, it has no size known at compile time, so the compiler wouldn't know how much space to allocate.

> Why is it that I can successfully create a `Weak<RefCell<Part>>` from `Rc::downgrade()`

It is because `Rc<RefCell<Part>>` points to a structure that is already allocated. Compiler can reference it with a trait pointer even though it doesn't know whether it's a `Blah` or some other implementation of the `Part` trait.

> Is there a way for me to annotate `Weak::new()` to help the compiler

You can indeed annotate `Weak::new()`, pointing the compiler to the implementation of `Part` that you want instantiated, like this:

```
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};
use std::cell::RefCell;

pub trait Part {}

pub struct Blah {}

impl Part for Blah {}

fn main() {
    let blah = Blah {};
    lookup(Rc::new(RefCell::new(blah)));
}

fn lookup(part: Rc<RefCell<Part>>) -> Weak<RefCell<Part>> {
    if true {
        Rc::downgrade(&part)
    } else {
        Weak::<RefCell<Blah>>::new()
    }
}
```

Comment: that makes sense! follow-up question: if `Weak::new()` actually reserves memory, how would one actually initialize something in that space after `Weak::new()` is called?

Comment: @eiko Yeah, [Weak::new](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/rc/struct.Weak.html#method.new) reserves memory, presumably to avoid extra branching and memory that would've been required to make the value `Option`-al. But the value it left uninitialized. You're not supposed to use or initialize it. `Weak::upgrade` will always return `None`, because the reference counter is initialized to zero.

Comment: ah okay, that's what i assumed at first! my initial thought was "if `Weak::new()` will always be `None`, there's no reason it would need to allocate memory." but if it still needs to allocate memory for technical reasons, i can live with that. thank you!

Comment: @ArtemGr: I challenge the fact that the memory is actually required! Since it's never access anyway, it might as well never be allocated. On the other hand... I've tried really hard to avoid allocating that memory, and it's not as easy as it sounds.

Comment: I created a follow-up question about changing the implementation of `Weak::new` to avoid the over-allocation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574711/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-weaknew-from-over-allocating

Comment: @MatthieuM. Absolutely, the allocation is **not** required, but it's a reasonable implementation trade-off, IMHO.

Comment: @MatthieuM. i fully support this excellent debate and will be following your other question! ^-^

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR: Fat pointers are hard.**

And therefore you need to specify the *concrete* type explicitly before coercion takes place:

```
Weak::<RefCell<Blah>>::new()
```

*Note: if `Blah` takes a lot of memory, create a Zero-Sized Type `Fool`, implement `Part` for it (all functions `unimplemented!()`), then use `Weak::<RefCell<Fool>>::new()` to avoid allocating memory uselessly.*

---

I believe that the underlying issue is simply one of implementation issue.

It does not seem unfixable, but may require quite some work to cover all corner cases.

---

First, let's expose the issue.

The implementation of `Weak::new`:

```
impl<T> Weak<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Weak<T> {
        unsafe {
            Weak {
                ptr: Shared::new(Box::into_raw(box RcBox {
                    strong: Cell::new(0),
                    weak: Cell::new(1),
                    value: uninitialized(),
                })),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For homogeneity, all `Shared` elements are wrapping a `RcBox`, which contains two `Cell` (the counters) and the actual value.

The mere fact of building a `RcBox<T>` *requires* that the size of `T` be known, which is why unlike most `Weak` methods, `T` is NOT marked as `: ?Sized` in this `impl`.

---

Now, since the memory is left uninitialized, it is clear that it will never be used, so actually *any* size would have been fine.

This is supported by the fact that `RcBox` can actually carry unsized data, which is necessary to go from `RcBox<Struct>` to `RcBox<Trait>`, and therefore the `strong` and `weak` fields are always laid out *first* (only the last field can be unsized).

Thus, we would like

1. Allocate a `RcBox<()>`, which would save memory AND not require that `T` be `Sized`,
2. Then transmuted to `RcBox<T>`, whatever `T` is.

Alright, let's do it!

---

Our desired implementation will look something like this:

```
impl<T: ?Sized> Weak<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Weak<T> {
        unsafe {
            Weak {
                ptr: Shared::new(transmute(Box::into_raw(box RcBox {
                    strong: Cell::new(0),
                    weak: Cell::new(1),
                    value: (),
                }))),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which utterly fails to compile.

Why? Because `*mut RcBox<()>` is a thin pointer, whereas `*mut RcBox<T>` is either a thin pointer OR a fat pointer ([see raw memory representation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/raw/struct.TraitObject.html)) depending on whether `T` is `Sized` or `!Sized`.

Now, trait pointers [can be handled](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0cd75b9e3303cb086b7a36011cbac557&version=nightly&backtrace=1) (**warning: contains a simplified and totally unsafe implementation of `Rc`**) with the following implementation of `Weak::new`:

```
impl<T: ?Sized> Weak<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Weak<T> {
        unsafe {
            let boxed = Box::into_raw(box RcBox {
                strong: Cell::new(0),
                weak: Cell::new(1),
                value: (),
            });

            let ptr = if size_of::<*mut ()>() == size_of::<*mut T>() {
                let ptr: *mut RcBox<T> = transmute_copy(&boxed);
                ptr
            } else {
                let ptr: *mut RcBox<T> = transmute_copy(&TraitObject {
                    data: boxed as *mut (),
                    vtable: null_mut(),
                });
                ptr
            };

            Weak { ptr: Shared::new(ptr) }
        }
    }
}
```

However this implementation *only accounts for trait pointers*, and there are other kinds of fat pointers for which it would... probably completely break down.