# Is there a way to prevent Weak::new() from over allocating?

Tags: rust

*Follow-up of [Why doesn't Weak::new() work when Rc::downgrade() does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573591/why-doesnt-weaknew-work-when-rcdowngrade-does/44574351#44574351)*

When attempting to implement `Weak::new()` in a way that would NOT require it to allocate memory for the underlying type even though it is never going to be used, I hit a roadblock.

The definition of `RcBox<T>` is rather simple:

```
struct RcBox<T: ?Sized> {
    strong: Cell<usize>,
    weak: Cell<usize>,
    value: T,
}
```

And the goal here is to create a `RcBox<T>` which will actually NOT contain any `value`. Essentially, a `RcBox<()>`.

However, there is a snag. `*mut RcBox<()>` is a thin pointer but `*mut RcBox<T>` is potentially a fat pointer. We have the data part of this fat pointer right, but there are many different cases of fat pointers so attempting to synthetize the rest is **hard**.

As can be seen in the linked question, I can make it work for just trait objects:

```
impl<T: ?Sized> Weak<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Weak<T> {
        unsafe {
            let boxed = Box::into_raw(box RcBox {
                strong: Cell::new(0),
                weak: Cell::new(1),
                value: (),
            });

            let ptr = if size_of::<*mut ()>() == size_of::<*mut T>() {
                let ptr: *mut RcBox<T> = transmute_copy(&boxed);
                ptr
            } else {
                let ptr: *mut RcBox<T> = transmute_copy(&TraitObject {
                    data: boxed as *mut (),
                    vtable: null_mut(),
                });
                ptr
            };

            Weak { ptr: Shared::new(ptr) }
        }
    }
}
```

However this won't work with `str` (for example).

I made another attempt trying to isolate the fixed-size portion of `RcBox` while letting the compiler infer the fat part of the pointer:

```
struct RcBox<T: ?Sized> {
    counters: RcBoxCounters<T>,
    value: T,
}

struct RcBoxCounters<T: ?Sized> {
    strong: Cell<usize>,
    weak: Cell<usize>,
    _phantom: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T: ?Sized> Weak<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Weak<T> {
        unsafe {
            let boxed = Box::into_raw(box RcBox::Counters::new(0, 1));
            Weak { ptr: Shared::new(boxed as *mut RcBox<T>) }
        }
    }
}
```

which sounds very clever until the compiler squashes your enthusiasm:

> ```
> error[E0375]: implementing the trait `CoerceUnsized` requires multiple coercions
>   --> <anon>:58:40
>    |
> 58 | impl<T: ?Sized + Unsize<U>, U: ?Sized> CoerceUnsized<RcBox<U>> for RcBox<T> {}
>    |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ requires multiple coercions
>    |
>    = note: `CoerceUnsized` may only be implemented for a coercion between structures with one field being coerced
>    = note: currently, 2 fields need coercions: counters (RcBoxCounters<T> to RcBoxCounters<U>), value (T to U)
> ```

That is:

- I think that to let the compiler synthesize the fat part I need a `PhantomData` in `RcBoxCounters`,
- however doing so requires 2 conversions for the coercion, which is not allowed.

---

So, is there a way to fix `Weak::new()` so that it stops allocating extraneous (unnecessary) memory?

*Note: I do mean allocating only space for the two counters, allocating large and trimming afterward does NOT help.*

*Note: It has been remarked that one could use an `Option` or special value to denote the absence of value. This requires branching on each method, which may not be desirable. I prefer learning to fiddle with fat pointers.*

Comment: This seems like a weird (and needlessly convoluted) way to go about solving it.  If I was doing this, I'd have a placeholder value for "there is not and never has been a backing object" and avoid the heap allocation entirely.  I believe `Vec` does this to avoid heap-allocating for empty vectors; there's a "null but not actually 0" pointer value.

Comment: @DK.: That's another solution indeed; essentially using `Option<Shared<..>>`. However this does require one more branch for each method, so maybe a tiny allocation yields better code? In any case, this is mostly an excuse (on my side) to better understand how to synthetize fat pointers out of thin air.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, and it was actually submitted to the standard library:

- [Arc: remove unused allocation from Weak::new()](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/50357)
- [Rc: remove unused allocation and fix segfault in Weak::new()](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/51901)

> This change makes it so that Weak::new() allocates no memory at all. Instead, it is created with a null pointer. The only things done with a Weak are trying to upgrade, cloning, and dropping, meaning there are very few places that the code actually needs to check if the pointer is null.

Comment: And more specifically, it uses: [`NonNull::dangling()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/ptr.rs.html#2688-2693), a ready-made dangling pointer.